# Show changes with diff using AIDE

Tags: debian, diff, aide

is it possible to compare the changed file when using AIDE? In the automatic Email only the SHA256 will be compared. It would be pretty cool if i can see what changed, maybe with a diff or something.

Thanks for your response!
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. AIDE can’t offer you a diff.

For AIDE to be able to generate such a diff, it would have to have an original copy of every file you monitor.

And as far as I know AIDE does not create such copies, it only creates a list of hashes. (And a list of hashes is much smaller than a full copy of your system so you can easily put the AIDE hashes on a removable medium out of reach from an adversary getting access to your server. )